# How to extract QAbstractScrollArea data?

Tags: qt, qt5, disassembly

I'd like to extract text data in the QAbstractScrollArea in the below.

[image: code data to extract]

It is IDA pro disassemble data I want to extract and IDA pro provides 'IDApython' library to extract their data. but It provides only restricted function. For example, they provide only instruction data extract function.

So, even I wanted following data '.text:00401020                 push    offset unk_4543A4 ; Src', IDA only extract push    offset unk_4543A4.

I'v tried several combinations of functions but It is impossible to extract all data including comments and other data section.

To solve this issue, I've tried another method using 'FormToPyQtWidget' function IDApython provides as bellow.

```
tform = idaapi.find_widget("IDA View-A")
view_widget = idaapi.PluginForm.FormToPyQtWidget(tform)
```

By printing view_widget, I knew that IDA View-A in the screenshot is QAbstractScrollArea. But I could not find any method to extract the data from QAbstractScrollArea including docs(https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html) and other websites.

Is there any method to extract text data from QAbstractScrollArea data?

Comment: Do you know that you can look into the original source code on [woboq.org](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractscrollarea.cpp.html)? This is surely more readable as any reverse-engineered source code (especially if the original was written in C++).

Comment: Which data do you want to extract from `QAbstractScrollArea`? I've some doubts that the `QAbstracScrollArea` itself has been instanced. Instead, I would assume the instance is of a class derived from `QAbstractScrollArea`. This might be the reason why you couldn't find the resp. data you was looking for...

Comment: ...and if this was text data then it could have been a [QTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) or [QPlainTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html)...
(I'm not sure what you exactly are looking for. AFAIK, `.text` in Assembly refers to code sections but has nothing to do with any text the code may (or may not) store or process.)